# How can I retrieve a file in a directory with many subfolders without declaring them one by one using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, subdirectory

I have a batch file that retrieves a file in a directory but only in one folder and by declaring the exact folder. How can I change my batch file to a dynamic one so it can retrieve the specific file within the `subfolders`.

I declared this line of code in my batch file that specifies the folder where the file should be retrieve.

call `FTPDownload("SERVER","USERNAME","PASSWORD","D:dir1/dir2/dir3/",fyldt_currentday)`

How can I retrieve the file within all the `subfolders` of the `dir3` without declaring it one by one?

Answer (score 4):

You could simply get the character length of the current directory, and remove them from your absolute list

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%n in (1 1 500) do if "!__cd__:~%%n,1!" neq "" set /a "len=%%n+1"
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /r . %%g in (*.log) do (
  set "absPath=%%g"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "relPath=!absPath:~%len%!"
  echo(!relPath!
  endlocal
)
```